# Magento Magmi more then one source csv

Tags: magento, import

We are using Magmi for our webshop to import automaticly stock in our Magento shop. We have several csv sources with stock updates. Is it possible to set more then one csv to import from?

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only import 1 file per import process.  With that being said, you could run multiple imports by specifying the filesnames using the [Magmi CLI](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_command_line).

All you have to do is create a bash script that **loops** through your files and calls the following (replace profile with the Magmi profile you want to use, and the filename with the path to your CSV file):

```
php magmi.cli.php -profile=myprofile -mode=create -CSV:filename="/home/myuser/toto.csv"
```